# xCode 6 centre of image not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I updated to Xcode 6 a long time ago. When I had Xcode 5 the game was working fine, and on iOS 7 it works fine, but on Xcode 6 / iOS 8 it does not work. Ive got an arc4random(), which doesn't work - it's meant to select a random number between 9 and which ever number it is the x and y coordinates of an image changes - so I tried using other versions of arc4random(), but they never worked. However i'm now confused because it does select a random number, and it does run the switch statement correctly, but coordinates  the of the image does not change?? So is it my arc4random() or .center does not work on iOS 8 / Xcode 6?? (I'm using objective-c and NOT swift)

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender
{
    int Place = arc4random() % 9;
    NSLog(@"The number is: %i", Place);
    Switch(Place) {
        case 0:
              NSLog(@"One is Selected"):
              Image.center = CGPointMake(10,10);
              break;
        case 1:
              Image.center = CGPointMake(20,20);
              NSLog(@"Two is selected");
              break; 
        etc...
}
```

Comment: It looks like you might be referencing the wrong object. Is `Image:` the name of your selector and `Image` the name of your UIView? You should really consider changing these to make it clearer. "Future Reakol" will thank you.

Consider using `arc4random_uniform(9)` instead. It should introduce less bias in your random number generation.

Comment: Yeah I've already tried using arc4random_uiform(), and rand() and random() and int(rand()), and none worked. Image (action) is just a name for the button, and Image is the UIImageView.

Comment: What does not working mean? Does the image view not move at all? Was Image created in code or IB? Are you using auto layout? You really should try to stick with Objective-C naming conventions, and start your method and property names with lower case letters. Also give your objects and methods better names that make what they are/do clearer.

Comment: You need to describe IN DETAIL what the current (wrong) behaviour is and what the correct behaviour should be. Also include the output from your `NSLog` statements. Also, where is `Image` defined (this should be renamed to something more descriptive anyway)? And use `arc4random_uniform(9)` which will return a number between 0 and 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't turn off autolayout, so since the game was made for ios7 the random placement of the number didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there's just some confusion about naming? What happens if you change the name of your UIImageView object `Image` to something else that doesn't have the same name as your method?